# What is the variable/method to address the content type in a template file?

Tags: theming, 8

What is the variable/method to address/fetch a particular content type in template files?

What variable/method shall I put at the blank space so my statement/logic will be like `if contentType == 'article'`?

```
{% if ____________ %}
  ......
  ........
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

call the getType method of the node object, like:
 `node.getType() == 'article'`